# Get location of android widget

Tags: android

Is there any way to retrieve position/location of android widget which is activated in android device, like whether its on lock screen, home screen etc. In lock screen is it the main widget displayed.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 2.1 and later, with some select home screens, you can find out where an app widget resides when it is clicked via getSourceBounds() -- this value is attached to any Intent you spawn via a PendingIntent via setOnClickPendingIntent().

However:

this only works on Android 2.1 and newer
not all home screens might do this, as this is part of the Launcher code IIRC
the coordinates are in pixels IIRC
there is no way to interrogate the home screen to find out this information any other way, since there is no API to interact with the home screen
Hence, I think your stated goal ("Depending on whether it's on the top of the desktop or at the bottom different layouts for the widget will be chosen") is impossible, I think.